# Provide access for input controls on user role bases

Tags: jasperserver

I have business requirements for a Jasper report where I have to provide an access on the input controls (date/check box/text fields etc) of the Jasper report on the bases on the user role. Is it possible with JasperReports? I am using *JasperReports Server 6.0.0*.

Comment: Yes it is possible. First of all let us know how you are integrating your reports with your application

Comment: As of now, I have to run the Jasper reports only on the Jasper Server version(6.0.0). Need not to integrate with application.